# Add timer to Python quiz

Tags: python

during my learning with python I wrote this quiz. All is good and works like charm but I want to add to kinds of timers:

- overall timer (e.g. you have 5 minutes of time)
- question timer (e.g. you have 1 minute max per question

I did a lot of googling and just made this to work

```
import time
start = time.time()
end = start + 5*60
...
if time.time() < end:
Question
...
```

This results in having unlimited time for the last question.

Do you have any idea of implementing the timers? :)

This is my quizcode:

```
import csv

with open('QandA.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    data = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
G = 0
P = 1

# Question Loop
for i in range(len(data)):
    solution = list(data[i][1].split(","))
    answer = input(data[i][0])
    if answer.casefold() in (name.casefold() for name in solution):
        print("Richtig", data[i][2])
        G = G + P
        P = P * 2
    else:
        print("Falsch", data[i][3])
        P = 1

# Result
print("Total Points:", G)
input("End of the game. press <Enter> to exit")
quit()
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just check that the time taken is less than 1 or 5 minutes after each/all question? Or abort the entry prompt after 1 minute? Or show a live countdown clock?

Comment: Also if all your `quizcode` is inside `if time.timer() < end:`, you will have infinite time because your "question loop" has no way of stopping unless you check `if time... < end` from within the question loop and you have to explicitly `break` out to end the game? Need more info to accurately solve this problem.

Comment: i want to do the following:

Game has 5 Minutes time in total
inside question Loop - max 1 Minute per question

Comment: and yes, once time is up, it should break immediately and display the end score

Comment: break looks promising. I need to send a break when the time is up..

Comment: maybe having a timer in the main thread and the game in a thread running. when the total timer is over, it kills the thread?

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of countdown timer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/

is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I put my game into a function. Tried to put this function inside the countdown function, but i still can answer the full quiz even if i just set 1 second.

Comment: In what form is the exemplary data row? So I could make my own question and answer and provide you with a possible answer

Comment: my whole code is above. my csv has in the columns: Question, Answer (comma seperated), Answer for correct, Answer for wrong;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).